# How to iterate over a list passed as function argument?

Tags: python, list, function, loops, iterator

Need help in understanding the efficient and proper way of handling iterating a list when passed as function argument. Here's some sample code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

items = [{'freq':'qtrly','date':'01/02/2019','amount':40,'quantity':5}, {'freq':'annly','date':'04/06/2018','amount':20,'quantity':4}]

def splitItems(Item, mmmm):
    print("splitItem() function was called")
    finalRows = []
    for itm in Item:
        print("Called from within 1st for-loop")
        print("Original List: ", itm)
        for e in range(mmmm):
            print("Called from within 2nd for-loop")
            new = itm.copy()
            new['date']  = datetime.strptime(itm['date'],'%m/%d/%Y') + relativedelta(months=+e)
            new['amount'] = itm['amount'] / mmmm
            new['quantity'] = itm['quantity'] / mmmm
            finalRows.append(new)
            print("New List: ", datetime.strftime(new['date'],'%m/%d/%Y'), new['amount'],new['quantity'])
    return finalRows

for i in items:
    freq = i['freq']
    final = items
    if freq == 'qtrly':
        print('frequency is: ',freq)
        final = splitItems(items,3)
    elif freq == 'annly':
        print('frequency is: ',freq)
        final = splitItems(items,12)
    elif freq == 'semi-annly':
        print('frequency is: ',freq)
        final = splitItems(items,6)
    else:
        None
```

I get correct results when there's only 1 row/tuple in the list (i.e. item). For example, if there's only 1 row which has freq = 'qtrly'; then the function yields correct output, i.e.:

```
frequency is:  qtrly
splitItem() function was called
Called from within 1st for-loop
Original List:  {'freq': 'qtrly', 'date': '01/02/2019', 'amount': 40, 'quantity': 5}
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  01/02/2019 13.333333333333334 1.6666666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  02/02/2019 13.333333333333334 1.6666666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  03/02/2019 13.333333333333334 1.6666666666666667
```

However, with more than 1 tuples/rows/items in the list, it first iterates 3 times for "qtrly" for each items in the list and then 12 times for "annly" for the same tuples/rows, like below and which isn't correct:

```
frequency is:  qtrly
splitItem() function was called
Called from within 1st for-loop
Original List:  {'freq': 'qtrly', 'date': '01/02/2019', 'amount': 40, 'quantity': 5}
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  01/02/2019 13.333333333333334 1.6666666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  02/02/2019 13.333333333333334 1.6666666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  03/02/2019 13.333333333333334 1.6666666666666667
Called from within 1st for-loop
Original List:  {'freq': 'annly', 'date': '04/06/2018', 'amount': 20, 'quantity': 4}
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  04/06/2018 6.666666666666667 1.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  05/06/2018 6.666666666666667 1.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  06/06/2018 6.666666666666667 1.3333333333333333
frequency is:  annly
splitItem() function was called
Called from within 1st for-loop
Original List:  {'freq': 'qtrly', 'date': '01/02/2019', 'amount': 40, 'quantity': 5}
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  01/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  02/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  03/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  04/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  05/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  06/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  07/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  08/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  09/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  10/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  11/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  12/02/2019 3.3333333333333335 0.4166666666666667
Called from within 1st for-loop
Original List:  {'freq': 'annly', 'date': '04/06/2018', 'amount': 20, 'quantity': 4}
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  04/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  05/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  06/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  07/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  08/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  09/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  10/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  11/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  12/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  01/06/2019 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  02/06/2019 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  03/06/2019 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
```

**Expected output is:**

```
frequency is:  qtrly
splitItem() function was called
Called from within 1st for-loop
Original List:  {'freq': 'qtrly', 'date': '01/02/2019', 'amount': 40, 'quantity': 5}
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  01/02/2019 13.333333333333334 1.6666666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  02/02/2019 13.333333333333334 1.6666666666666667
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  03/02/2019 13.333333333333334 1.6666666666666667

frequency is:  annly
splitItem() function was called
Called from within 1st for-loop
Original List:  {'freq': 'annly', 'date': '04/06/2018', 'amount': 20, 'quantity': 4}
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  04/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  05/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  06/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  07/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  08/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  09/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  10/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  11/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  12/06/2018 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  01/06/2019 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  02/06/2019 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
Called from within 2nd for-loop
New List:  03/06/2019 1.6666666666666667 0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: Your list is not valid. You can't have `key: value` entries in a list, they can only be in a dictionary.

Comment: It looks like it's just a typo, you need `{` before `'freq':'annly'`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You're looping through the list when you do `for i in items`. Why are you looping through the list again in `splitItems()`?

Comment: It seems like the function should just process one item, not loop through all of them again.

Comment: I corrected the typo. It is a list of tuples/rows. What am trying to do is - 1st iteration to check frequency of each list items (tuple/row) and then within the function passing that list item (row) and then depending on the frequency, copying the list item tuple/row that many times and appending into a new list after doing some transformations.

Comment: You're not passing the list item, you're passing the whole list, and iterating over the list again in the function. Just pass `i` instead if `items`, and get rid of the loop in `splitItems()`

Comment: Aah, I see.... my bad, glad that you catched that...I was passing entire list ...yes, that makes perfect sense now of unnecessary looping within splitItems (). thanks !!